# Is this database schema for reservation and incidentals billings correct?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm creating a database design for reservation billing and incidental billing. I'm having a hard time on figuring out how to indicate if the payment is for incidentals or the reservation. Will this design work? and what can I change to improve it.

[image: Database schema]

Comment: What happens if one payment is for several reservations and incidentals?  You can treat payments like orders.  Have a payment total table and a payment detail table.  The payment detail table should match up payments with reservations and incidentals.  If the payment doesn't cover all costs, you create partial payment detail rows.

Answer (score 0):

`Payment_transaction.payment_for` possibly could use an FK.

Then a simple join should work:

```
select pf.*  -- 'Booking' / 'Incidentals'
       ,pt.* 
from payment_transactions pt
inner join payment_for pf on pt.payment_for = pf.id
-- join anything else
-- Condition as needed e.g.
        --  where pf.label in ('booking')
```

Comment: Constraints are not needed to make joins "work".